# Trying to Export Memory Video

Tags: macos, photos, video

I have tried several times to "Export Memory Video" from MacOS Photos Version 7.0 (460.0.120) but nothing seems to happen. I can successfully export images, but I can't find any video in the specified folder.

Comment: What model Mac and which version of macOS?

Comment: Model Name: MacBook
  Model Identifier: MacBook9,1
  Processor Name: Dual-Core Intel Core m3
  Processor Speed: 1.1 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
macOS 12.7.2 (21G1974)